# Java Button Width

Tags: java, swing, button, size, width

I've tried to [use this](http://pastebin.com/0iqjeNCM) and it doesn't work

```
singleplayerButton.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 100);
```

I dont know why though, can anybody help me out with this?

My full page code is [here](http://pastebin.com/iuMUkPrS)

```
package gmine;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gmine implements ActionListener {
        JFrame interfaceFrame;
        JButton singleplayerButton, multiplayerButton, optionsButton, quitButton;

        public gmine() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
                interfaceFrame = new JFrame("G-Mine B0.4");
                interfaceFrame.setSize(800,600);
                interfaceFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,1, 20, 15));

                singleplayerButton = new JButton("SinglePLayer");
                singleplayerButton.addActionListener(this);
                interfaceFrame.add(singleplayerButton);
                singleplayerButton.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 100);

                multiplayerButton = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
                multiplayerButton.addActionListener(this);
                interfaceFrame.add(multiplayerButton);

                optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
                optionsButton.addActionListener(this);
                interfaceFrame.add(optionsButton);

                quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
                quitButton.addActionListener(this);
                interfaceFrame.add(quitButton);

                interfaceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                interfaceFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                new gmine();
        }
}
```

im trying to accomplish making the buttons smaller, so not touching the side of the page.

Comment: What are you trying to acomplish with this line of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I personally would use a layout manager that will give you more flexibility in deciding how the buttons are laid out and makes a great effort to honor your components preferred size, but gives you the freedom to make adjustments to as you need...

For me, that's `GridBagLayout`

[image]

```
public class ButtonsLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonsLayout();
    }

    public ButtonsLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new MenuPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton singleplayerButton = new JButton("SinglePLayer");
            JButton multiplayerButton = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
            JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
            JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.ipadx = 20;
            gbc.ipady = 20;

            add(singleplayerButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(multiplayerButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(optionsButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(quitButton, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I've used `ipadx` and `ipady` of the `GridBagConstraints` to increase the width and height of the components through the layout manager, as well as using the `HORIZONTAL` fill to make all the components the same width.

Have a look at

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

For more information

Comment: That is awesome, im going to use this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

- First of all when you use `LayoutManager`, then the **position of the component and its size is controlled** by the `LayoutManager` of the **direct Parent Compoenent** on when the Component is being placed.. 

  **Eg:** 
  Placing a JButton on JFrame, then JFrame's LayoutManager controls the position and size of the JButton.
- I would also recommend you to use `GroupLayout` which was developed by NetBeans team in 2005, and you can use the [`WindowsBuilderPro`](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/), now free from Google.

Answer (score 2):

The `GridLayout` manager will give equal size to all components. You could try using a different layout manager and then use `setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize)` on your components to size them correctly.

As a different example, you could also place a `JPanel` on top of your `JFrame` and place the buttons there.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid using `setPreferredSize` if possible, it runs you straight into problems with different look and feels and differences in fonts and DPI issues...it's almost as bad as `null` layouts...almost ;) - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use one of the answers above. Now the program wont show. it just terminates.

```
package gmine;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gmine {
        JFrame interfaceFrame;
        JButton singleplayerButton, multiplayerButton, optionsButton, quitButton;


    public void ButtonsLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("G-Mine");
                interfaceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                interfaceFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                interfaceFrame.setSize(800,600);
                interfaceFrame.add(new MenuPane());
                interfaceFrame.pack();
                interfaceFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                interfaceFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton singleplayerButton = new JButton("SinglePLayer");
            JButton multiplayerButton = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
            JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
            JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.ipadx = 20;
            gbc.ipady = 20;

            add(singleplayerButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(multiplayerButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(optionsButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(quitButton, gbc);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new gmine();
    }
```

}

Comment: There's no constructor. Try changing `public void ButtonsLayout()` to `public gmine`

Comment: I do that and i get this in my console.

Comment: I do that and i get this in my console.
http://pastebin.com/23y5GifJ

And here is the full script
http://pastebin.com/GBLB382J

Comment: Your create a new `JFrame`, but then reference the instance variable which is `null`.  Change the line `JFrame frame = new JFrame("G-Mine");` to something more like `interfaceFrame = new JFrame("G-Mine");`

Comment: Ok it works now, but when i open it, it is the size of the buttons, now my set width.

interfaceFrame.setSize(800,600);

why?

Comment: This interfaceFrame.pack() is packing the window down to its preferred size

Comment: so i remove that? so i get my setSize(); ?

Comment: Without the influence of `pack`, the `setSize` values should now remain

Comment: ok, that works great, http://i.imgur.com/XPuwW.png .
Now to add my image logo, and set the background color of black

Comment: Mad, why wont interfaceFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK); make the  bg black?

Comment: Probably because what you need to change is the content pane.  Try interfaceFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19013/discussion-between-heloic-and-madprogrammer)