# Swing - Adding a image into GUI

Tags: java, image, swing

So, following from my last post [Java Button Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136701/java-button-width) im looking to add some images and set a background color. Ive tried a few things, just everytime i do it. It always gives me errors.

i've tried

```
setBackground(args);
```

and

```
img = addImage("image.png");
```

they dont work for me. Can somebody give me a hand please?

Ok i tried the post made by Disha. And the applet still stays the same color, not black

http://pastebin.com/iijj7fSr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the beginning, Please do learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and stick to them.

In order for you to provide a background Color to your `JFrame`, since you had added one `JPanel` to the `CENTER`.
Hence you cannot get one background color by writing :

```
interfaceFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
```

Now you have to set the opaque property of the `JPanel`  to true and set one Background color for the same like :

```
setOpaque(true);
setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

inside your **MenuPane**  Class's constructor.

Here here is your modified code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gmine {
        JFrame interfaceFrame;
        JButton singleplayerButton, multiplayerButton, optionsButton, quitButton;


        public Gmine() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    interfaceFrame = new JFrame("G-Mine");
                    interfaceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    interfaceFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    interfaceFrame.setSize(800,500);
                    //interfaceFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
                    interfaceFrame.add(new MenuPane());
                    interfaceFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    interfaceFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

            public MenuPane() {
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                setOpaque(true);
                setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                singleplayerButton = new JButton("SinglePLayer");
                multiplayerButton = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
                optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
                quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.ipadx = 20;
                gbc.ipady = 20;

                add(singleplayerButton, gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                add(multiplayerButton, gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                add(optionsButton, gbc);
                gbc.gridy++;
                add(quitButton, gbc);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Gmine();
        }
}
```

Now in order to add images to your project you can either see this answer for how to [add images to your Project in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and you can get help from this small sample code as well which is as follows :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintingExample
{
    private CustomPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField userField;
    private JPasswordField passField;
    private JButton loginButton;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new CustomPanel();        

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PaintingExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    private BufferedImage image;

    public CustomPanel()
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5));
        try
        {
            /*
             * Since Images are Application Resources,
             * it's always best to access them in the
             * form of a URL, instead of File, as you are doing.
             * Uncomment this below line and watch this answer
             * of mine, as to HOW TO ADD IMAGES TO THE PROJECT
             * https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230
             * In order to access images with getClass().getResource(path)
             * here your Directory structure has to be like this
             *                 Project
             *                    |
             *         ------------------------
             *         |                      |
             *        bin                    src
             *         |                      |
             *     ---------             .java files             
             *     |       |                   
             *  package   image(folder)
             *  ( or              |
             *   .class        404error.jpg
             *   files, if
             *   no package
             *   exists.)
             */
            //image = ImageIO.read(
            //      getClass().getResource(
            //              "/image/404error.jpg"));
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                        "http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/" + 
                                "gaganisonline/images/404error.jpg"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch image.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Make this one customary habbit,
     * of overriding this method, when
     * you extends a JPanel/JComponent,
     * to define it's Preferred Size.
     * Now in this case we want it to be 
     * as big as the Image itself.
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    }

    /*
     * This is where the actual Painting
     * Code for the JPanel/JComponent
     * goes. Here we will draw the image.
     * Here the first line super.paintComponent(...),
     * means we want the JPanel to be drawn the usual 
     * Java way first, then later on we will
     * add our image to it, by writing the other line,
     * g.drawImage(...).
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Do uncomment the lines given below and add your image at the specified location :

```
image = ImageIO.read(
      getClass().getResource(
              "/image/404error.jpg"));
```

If still in doubt, ask any question you might have, I'll try to provide information, if it is within my bounds :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is solution you are looking for:

1. Create a package called like `com.icon`
2. Add your icons to that package (copy/paste)
3. You will add icon on button like this:

   ```
   button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(NameOfClass.class.getResource("/com/icon/nameOfIcon.png")));
   ```

P.S. Make sure they are in .png format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
for set background color you use `setBackground(Color.color_name);` and for set image try below code

```
Image bgImage= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("wallpaper_adrift.jpg");
contentPane.setBackgroundImage(bgImage);
```

Also refers to http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/346524/how-to-set-background-image-in-java-swing  and  [How to set an image as a background for Frame in Swing GUI of java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466240/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-for-frame-in-swing-gui-of-java)